# ghostscript for windows: PDF display in Landscape

Tags: ghostscript

I have the following line to create a PDF file:
gpcl6win64 -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o %2 %1

the problem is that when I have a file in Landscape mode, it also display that way and I have to rotate the page each time.  Is there a way view the PDF file displayed in the Portrait format?
the help on the DOS command is not very useful and other documented command on the web does not work.

Thanks,
Qumars

Answer (score 0):

With PCL the options are sharply limited, there's no way to adjust the CTM being used, so the page requested by the PCL file will be what is emitted in the PDF file.

It would help (a lot) to post an example of the kind of file causing you a problem, its very difficult to know what ot suggest without seeing why there's a problem.

Ghostscript doesn't come with a help file, its documentation is [here](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.23/Readme.htm) and the documentation specific to the high level output devices is [here](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.23/VectorDevices.htm)

Comment: When I export my data, I add PCL6 header to it which makes it ready be be printed by any HP compatible printer.  Depending to a the report it can be Portrait or landscape,  After PCL file is created I convert it to a PDF file on a window machine, we are just experimenting with the  gpcl6win64 and app

Comment: none of other command seems to work and it displays as it is was coded to print.  We currently have another software which displays the the PDF in a Portrait  format.

Comment: So what you are saying, if I understand you, is that you have a single PDF which is drawn in 2 different ways by two different applications. Seems to me that one of the applications is incorrect. Without seeing your PCL file I can't help you with this. I doubt your PCL6 header has anything to do with it, since it will likely be overridden by anything in the following file. I'd also note that old PCL printers don't understand PCL6 (PCL-XL) so you can't add a PCL6 header which makes it 'ready to be printed by **any** HP compatible printer'